# Using axios post response in the jsx react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I want to take the data response from the Axios post, and display it on the page:

```js
import React, { useRef} from 'react';
import logo from './assets/img/lupa.png';
import { Form } from "@unform/web";
import Input from './components/forms/input';
import * as Yup from "yup";
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';



function App() {
  
  const formRef = useRef(null);

  async function handleSubmit(data, ){

    try{
      const schema = Yup.object().shape({

        nn: Yup.number().min(8,"O campo eh obrigatorio e precisa ter 8 ou mais caracteres")

      })
      await schema.validate(data)
      console.log(data)
    }catch(err){
      if(err instanceof Yup.ValidationError){
        console.log(err)
      }}

      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api", data).then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  }


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>$ Search $</h2>
        </div>
        <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Input name="nn" type="number"/>
          <button type='submit'>buscar</button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }


export default App;
```

But I don't know how to work with that res.data and how to display it on the page by the jsx react, I tried to use useState and set it in the axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api", data).then(res => setState(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err)); - but when I console.log someState it brings an object null, i tried to display on the page using

```js
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>$ Search $</h2>
        </div>
        <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Input name="nn" type="number"/>
          <button type='submit'>buscar</button>
        </Form>
        {
          someState.length >=1 ? someState.map((some, idx) =>{
            return <p key={idx}>{some.data}</p>
          })
          : ""
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

but nothing were display! ( If you have some suggestion to change of the overall code, you can answer too ), How can I fix this 2 problems ? I want to learn moreThe first object Im printing my input, to check if it are working, and the second object its what I recieved from the axios post response(.then(res => console.log(res.data), I want to display this object "resultado"

```json
Object { nn: "00000000353" }

Object { ip: "200.1******", resultado: 961 }
​
ip: "200.1*****"
​
resultado: 961
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can display data fetched from an api properly in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856041/how-can-display-data-fetched-from-an-api-properly-in-react)

Answer (score -1):

See this nice post by digitalOcean **How to use axios in ReactJs**

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react

Hope you got a lot of help from this post.